# Creating an array between two integers w/ math.random as part of sequential search

Tags: java

I have an assignment where the user is asked for a number between 50 and 400. If the number is found in the array printed beforehand, the program should print the index location. If not, the program prints -1. My problem is I can't figure out how to make it so the array starts at 50, not 0.
This is my code thus far (ignore the comments):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment_7 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n,i,flag1 = 0; //setting all the variables 
        //flag is to indicate if a number was in the list
        int[] arra; // creating array
        arra = new int[100]; //initializing array
         for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)//start of loop for array itself
        {
            int randomNum = (int)(Math.random() * 401);//array need the number between 0 and 400 
            //(one less than 401 is maximum for randomization)
            arra[i] = randomNum; // setting array to random set of number between 0 and 400
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            
            System.out.print(arra[i]+" ");// array is printed
        }
        
            System.out.println("\nInsert a number between 50 and 400: ");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); // setting scanner
            n = s.nextInt(); // setting n (whatever number the user input) as int
            flag1=0; // if flag gets set to 1 it needs to be reset to 0
          
            for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
            {
                if(arra[i] == n) //if the number is indeed on the list
                {   
                    flag1=1; // in case the number is on the list
                    System.out.println(i+1);  
                }
            }
            if(flag1 == 0)// if the flag was set to 1 before (the number was in the list), this condition fails and drops down to the next
            {
                System.out.println(-1); // n is not found, so it prints -1
            } 
    }
}
```

Comment: java or javascript ? both ?

Comment: So do I understand this correct that your code currently produces random numbers from 0-400 and you want to know how to produce a random number from 50-400? If so: Just create a random number 0-350 and then add 50 to that random number.

Comment: have look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

I still remember the days back to school!

Just simply add the base value outside the random method, and subtract it from the upper bound:

```
int randomNum = 50 + ((int)(Math.random() * (400 - 50) + 1));
```

Of course, math expressions were expanded such that you can read the intend.

Answer (score 1):

### With current requirements

1. Need to use only array with linear scan
2. Prints the first seen occurrence(index) for a number (the number can appear multiple times)

`start + new Random().nextInt(end - start)` (includes start, excludes end)

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Assignment_7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int startRange = 50; // inclusive
        final int endRange = 400; // exclusive
        final int count = endRange - startRange;
        final Random random = new Random();

        int[] numbers = IntStream.range(0, count).map(i -> random.nextInt(count) + startRange).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        System.out.println("Insert a number between " + startRange + "(inclusive) and " + endRange + "(exclusive)");
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int guess = scanner.nextInt();

        boolean found = false;
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            if(numbers[index] == guess) {
                System.out.println(index);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found) {
            System.out.println(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

### Optimization

1. If other other data structures are allowed, then we can use `Map` for lookup.
2. Also, if the guess is performed many times, `Map` will surely help

```java
    static void efficientForRepeatedGuessAndLongRanges(int startRange, int endRange) {
        final int count = endRange - startRange;
        final Random random = new Random();
        int[] numbers = IntStream.range(0, count).map(i -> random.nextInt(count) + startRange).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        Map<Integer, Integer> valueToFirstSeenIndexMap = new HashMap<>();
        IntStream.range(0, count).forEach(i -> valueToFirstSeenIndexMap.putIfAbsent(numbers[i], i));
        int guess = -1;
        do {
            System.out.println("Guess a number between " + startRange + "(inclusive) and " + endRange + "(exclusive). Press -1 to stop");
            final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            guess = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println(valueToFirstSeenIndexMap.getOrDefault(guess, -1));
        } while (guess != -1);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake mate!! phew... : )

Comment: As a note, there is `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(lowerBound, upperBound)`, which is the preferred `Random` object to use for general situations. And, as you see, it has a `nextInt` overload that is easier to read and use, without any _math_.

Comment: @Zabuzard, Agreed, from math perspective, the overloaded method surely helps. `ThreadLocalRandom` reduces contention in multithreaded scenario. If you meant `general situations` as multithreaded environment, then it's on target. `Random` is thread-safe too but with possible performance penalty in multithreaded env. For the current use case, `Random` seems to be fine with simple math. If, we used parallelStream(), then `ThreadLocalRandom` would have be a good candidate. Thank you for sharing the feedback.

Comment: @Horse `ThreadLocalRandom` is not thread-safe, which gives it additional speed compared to `Random`. Also, it is implemented differently, better. That, plus the fact that it has nice extra methods, makes it the better candidate for 90% of use cases. It is the random to use by default. You should not use it if you need seeding or if you have to share an unsynchronized randomizer across multiple threads (which is rarely ever appropriate since even if u need multithreaded random numbers from the same generator, you can simply `synchronize` the call behind a wrapper).

Comment: @Zabuzard, Thank you. I should have been clear while mentioning about `ThreadLocalRandom`. My intent was, `ThreadLocalRandom.current().xyz()` will be highly efficient in multithreaded environments assuming the code flow always accesses the instance through `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`. Irrespective of `ThreadLocalRandom`, a code/library should never share any stateful mutable entity that is stored in the `ThreadLocal` to multiple threads. That is basically breaking the fundamental encapsulation in the context of `Thread`. (i never mentioned `ThreadLocalRandom` is thread-safe). Thanks again.

Comment: Summary of @Zabuzard's comment: Do not pass the reference of `ThreadLocalRandom` to multithreaded code or parallelStream(). Incorrect usage example: `ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current(); IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(i -> random.nextInt()).collect(Collectors.toList());` Correct usage of `ThreadLocalRandom` is to always access through `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`. Thanks again to @Zabuzard for educating about the need to write precise words to describe the problem.